# Windows Mobile: exception in Finalizer terminates program

Tags: c#, .net, windows-mobile, compact-framework

My Windows mobile application crashes sometimes with an exception that happens in the finalizer of `System.Net.HttpReadStream`.

It only happens sometimes, but then it brings down the whole program. Is there anything I can do to make the program continue when such an internal finalizer throws? Or alternatively, how can I prevent such an error?

Here's the stacktrace of the exception (not complete, since I have to type the whole thing...

```
ObjectDisposedException

at System.Threading.Timer.throwIfDisposed()
at System.Threading.Timer.Change(UInt32 dueTime, UInt32 period)
at ...
at System.Net.ContentLengthReadStream.doClose()
at System.Net.HttpReadStream.Finalize()
```

The calling code is:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(actionUrl);
request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
request.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = true;
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/json";

using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
{
    JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
    serializer.Serialize(writer, myRequestObject);
}

using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
        MyResultObject result = (MyResultObject)serializer.Deserialize(reader, typeof(MyResultObject));

        return result;
    }
}
```

---

### Update

> The calling code above is fine. The problem was caused by another `HttpWebRequest` where the response was not disposed. So remember, always dispose the response object, but especially in Compact Framework since it can bring down your whole application!

Comment: did you try putting the code inside a try catch block?

Comment: just to clarify: does this happen in the using in this code or is a stream Finalized by the GC?   And do you have a try/catch surrounding this?

Comment: It doesn't happen in the calling code, it happens sometime later when the GC kicks in. And since it's an internal .NET object, I can't put a try/catch around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that it was *another* `HttpWebRequest` causing this. The code in my question was fine, but the dispose of the response was missing in the other place.

Answer (score 2):

This [thread](http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.dotnet.framework.compactframework/browse_thread/thread/44ea29515c5cd2b0?pli=1) describes a similar problem.

The problem could be that you are returning inside the second using block. This way the response object won't get closed.

Comment: Then everything I ever learned about the using keywork or try/finally would be wrong...

Comment: But I'm also using .NET CF 3.5 like in the thread you mentioned. At least I'm not alone in this ;)

Comment: To be honest I don't know what happens when you are returning inside a using block. Perhaps in that case the finalizer isn't called. Anyway, it is bad practice to do so. Move the return statement out of the using blocks.

Comment: I don't think it's bad practice. If you return only at the end, every function looks like plain old C. Even in C++ I returned from inside a method and let the compiler figure out which destructors to call on the way out

Comment: I mean that you do something like this: using {...} return result; and not using { ... return result; }

Answer (score 1):

It won't hurt to close (Dipsose) the ResponseStream explicitly, as in:

```
using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
using (Stream respStream = response.GetResponseStream())
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(respStream))
{
  JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
  MyResultObject result =
    (MyResultObject)serializer.Deserialize(reader, typeof(MyResultObject));

  return result;
}
```

Otherwise it is up to the Reader object to close it's stream, a bit flaky.